# Iinvalid operands to binary % (have .char*. and .int.)

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming so this might be a stupid question...but I'm getting the following error:

```
45: error: invalid operands to binary % (have .char*. and .int.)
45: error: expected .). before string constant
```

Line 45 is the second printf function

some info:
charsInWord and indexOf both return an int value

```
int main() 
{ 
    char word [20]; 
    char c;

    printf("Enter a word and a character separated by a blank ");
    scanf("%s %c", word, &c);

    printf("\nInput word is "%c". contains %d input character. Index of %c in it is %d\n", word, charsInWord(word), c, indexOf(word, c));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"%c".` you should escape `"` since it is inside `printf`. Try this -- `\"%c\".`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to 'escape' the embedded quotes. Change:

```
printf("\nInput word is "%c". contains %d input character. Index of %c in it is %d\n", word, charsInWord(word), c, indexOf(word, c));
```

to:

```
printf("\nInput word is \"%c\". contains %d input character. Index of %c in it is %d\n", word, charsInWord(word), c, indexOf(word, c));
```

Or just use single quotes.

Comment: thanks! i just dropped the embedded quotes and that fixed that issue, but wow there is another error, I think i can handle it from here though :D

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
"Input word is "%c". contains %d input character."
```

to

```
"Input word is \"%s\". contains %d input character."
```

The escaping of quotes is to remove the error. The change from `%c` to `%s` is because you need `%s` to print out strings.

Comment: thanks for the string help! that fixed my other error and now my program works :) C is so different from java that im normally used to coding it, theres just some weird things that I keep forgetting in C like how there is no such thing as a "string" in C

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quotation marks in the format string.

```
printf("\nInput word is "%c". contains %d input character. Index of %c in it is %d\n", word, charsInWord(word), c, indexOf(word, c));
```

should be

```
printf("\nInput word is \"%c\". contains %d input character. Index of %c in it is %d\n", word, charsInWord(word), c, indexOf(word, c));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("\nInput word is "%c". contains %d input
```

For starters, you need to escape those quotation marks, like this:

```
printf("\nInput word is \"%c\". contains %d input
```

Next, make sure that the types of the parameters after the format string match the types expected by the format specifiers. That is, if you specify `%c`, make sure the corresponding parameter is a `char`. If you specify `%f`, make sure the corresponding parameter is a floating point type, and so on.

In this case, it looks like you might be trying to pass a string (`word`) for the first parameter, which you've specified as a character (`%c`). Use the `%s` format specifier instead if you mean to pass a `char[]` or `char*` (and make sure the string is null terminated).

Answer (score 0):

With a modern GCC library, you can remove the risk of the %s overrunning the buffer and scrambling your program's mind.  Checking the return value of scanf() is essential as well, for related reasons.  You can also break up your long lines a bit.  The example uses some standard library calls for the functions not defined in your example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() 
{ 
    char *word = 0;
    char c;

    printf("Enter a word and a character separated by a blank ");
    /* %ms is in GCC and the upcoming POSIX.1 standard */
    if(2 != scanf("%ms %c", &word, &c)) {
        fputs("oops, something went wrong in that input.\n", stderr);
        return -1;
    } 
    char *first = strchr(word, c);  /* NULL if not found */
    printf("\nInput word is \"%s\". contains %u input character. "
           "Index of %c in it is %ld\n",
           word, (unsigned int)strlen(word), c,
           first - word);  /* probably negative if it wasn't found */

    free(word);
    return 0;
}
```

Dealing with the unfound letters is left as an exercise... :-)